# generate list of objects with for loop

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

With this code I can fill my datagrid with values. Each item is one line.

gridDataVK4000 = {

```
                items : [{
                        "Datum" : GridDate[0],
                        "VERSENDET_PDF" : values[0][0],
                        "FAKTUREN_POSTBILLING" : values[1][0],
                        "VERSENDET_XML" : values[2][0],
                        "VERARBEITET_PDF_TCO" : values[3][0],
                        "VERARBEITET_XML_TCO" : values[4][0]
                    }, {
                        "Datum" : GridDate[1],
                        "VERSENDET_PDF" : values[0][1],
                        "FAKTUREN_POSTBILLING" : values[1][1],
                        "VERSENDET_XML" : values[2][1],
                        "VERARBEITET_PDF_TCO" : values[3][1],
                        "VERARBEITET_XML_TCO" : values[4][1]
                    }, {
                        "Datum" : GridDate[2],
                        "VERSENDET_PDF" : values[0][2],
                        "FAKTUREN_POSTBILLING" : values[1][2],
                        "VERSENDET_XML" : values[2][2],
                        "VERARBEITET_PDF_TCO" : values[3][2],
                        "VERARBEITET_XML_TCO" : values[4][2]
                    }....
```

Now I would like to write it shorter. This is my code so far. But I don't know how to get the values in the right structure:

```
var gridDataVK40001 = [];
            var key,
            i;
            for (i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
                key = i + "";
                gridDataVK40001.push({
                    "Datum" : GridDate[i],
                    "Fakturen_gesamt" : values[0][i],
                    "T1" : values[1][i],
                    "T2" : values[2][i],
                    "versendete PDF" : values[3][i],
                    "VERARBEITETE PDFs TSBS" : values[4][i],
                    "VERARBEITETE IDOCs TSBS" : values[5][i]
                });
            }
```

actual structure:

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

target structure:

```
Object {items: Array[15]}
```

any sugestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `gridDataVK40001` variable is an `Array` (`[]`). You need an `Object` (`{}`) with an `items` Array property:

```
var gridDataVK40001 = {items: []};
var key,
  i;
for (i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
  key = i + "";
  // we now push to the item property
  gridDataVK40001.items.push({
    "Datum": GridDate[i],
    "Fakturen_gesamt": values[0][i],
    "T1": values[1][i],
    "T2": values[2][i],
    "versendete PDF": values[3][i],
    "VERARBEITETE PDFs TSBS": values[4][i],
    "VERARBEITETE IDOCs TSBS": values[5][i]
  });
}
```